# Creating a usable 'str' object in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, object

I need to create a single `str` object for use in a much larger chunk of code.

I have a data set read in as a DataFrame called "testset."

```
testset = pd.read_csv('my_dataset_path')
```

Then I want to combine two of the columns, Latitude and Longitude, from "testset" into a single `str` object.

I want it to look like this:

```
u = u"""Latitude,Longitude
42.357778,-71.059444
39.952222,-75.163889
25.787778,-80.224167
30.267222, -97.763889"""
```

But when I try the following:

```
Lat = testset['Latitude'].astype(str) #creates a series
Long = testset['Longitude'].astype(str) #creates a series
Lat_str=Lat.str.cat(sep=' ') #coerces a 'str' object
Long_str=Long.str.cat(sep=' ') #coerces a 'str' object
u= Lat_str,Long_str
```

I just get a tuple from the two `str` objects.

I don't want to list each item in the final 'str' object "u" because the columns have over 1000 entries. Is there a way to streamline this to get the desired result? I have tried other variations for forming "u" but it's never quite right.

Comment: Rather than make strings immediately, have you tried zipping the two columns and using a list comprehension to concatenate the paired elements?

Comment: How would you get the 2nd row of latitude/longitude entries, can you put that in your question? You showed how to get the 1st row, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use pandas, the simplest would to use `to_csv()`:

```
u = testset[['Latitude' ,'Longitude']].to_csv(index=False)
print(u)
```

Output:

```
Latitude,Longitude
42.357778,-71.059444
39.952222,-75.163889
25.787778,-80.22416700000001
30.267221999999997,-97.763889
```

If you want to avoid the `30.267221999999997,`, round:

```
u = testset[['Latitude' ,'Longitude']].round(6).to_csv(index=False)
print(u)
```

Output:

```
Latitude,Longitude
42.357778,-71.059444
39.952222,-75.163889
25.787778,-80.224167
30.267222,-97.763889
```

Comment: Yup, this does it! I was looking into the stream editing IO Tools, but your method worked in the exact way I wanted. Thanks Mike.